# Rebol COLLECT: keep the order of the source data in a loop

Tags: rebol, rebol3, collect

There is some source data, like `[1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]`, four items as a group. I want to extract some data at specific positions, such as the first, third, and fourth from each group.

There is my code:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: copy []
foreach [p1 p2 p3 p4] data [ collect/into [keep p1 keep p3 keep p4] output ]
probe output    ;;the output is ["a" "c" "d" 1 3 4]
```

But what I really want is `[1 3 4 "a" "c" "d"]`. How can I keep the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All functions in Rebol which use the `/into` option use `insert` semantics. We added that option to allow incremental building without needing to make as many intermediate series, and to allow you to pick the type of target series, preallocate, and all sorts of other power user tricks. The `/into` option uses `insert` semantics because `insert` doesn't lose as much information as `append`.

Let's take your example but just use `collect`:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: collect [
    foreach [p1 p2 p3 p4] data [ keep p1 keep p3 keep p4 ]
]
probe output
```

That's the kind of simple code that `collect` is supposed to make it easier to write. But it's a bit slow, so let's try optimizing it a bit by using `/into`:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: copy []
foreach [p1 p2 p3 p4] data [
    output: collect/into [keep p1 keep p3 keep p4] output
]
probe head output
```

That is the standard model for `/into` code, and will make things output in the order you want. But it really doesn't have any advantages over using regular `collect`, since you don't preallocate the target block. This will save on reallocations:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: make block! 0.75 * length? data
foreach [p1 p2 p3 p4] data [
    output: collect/into [keep p1 keep p3 keep p4] output
]
probe head output
```

But `collect` itself can be a little slow because it's not native; it's mostly a convenience function. Fortunately, we have faster native functions, which use `/into` the same way:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: make block! 0.75 * length? data
foreach [p1 p2 p3 p4] data [ output: reduce/into [p1 p3 p4] output ]
probe head output
```

No non-native functions used there, this should be pretty fast.

Comment: Great explanation! `reduce` is quite fast.

Answer (score 3):

For a reason unknown to me, `collect` uses `insert` internally, so it inserts data at the beginning, not `append` them at the end. I hope someone can give an explanation why it's this way. Meanwhile, you can use good old `repend` to do the job:

```
data: [1 2 3 4 "a" "b" "c" "d"]
output: copy []
forskip data 4 [repend output [data/1 data/3 data/4]]
probe output    ;; [1 3 4 "a" "c" "d"]
```

Also, it's better to use `forskip` instead of `foreach` in this case, as you do not have to define variables and access just by index.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good solution. Thanks! if `collect` use the `insert` way, I just got an answer: just use `collect/into [keep p1 keep p3 keep p4] tail output`. I wonder if there is some performance loss if I do this.

Comment: That's great idea. That's also probably the reason, why `collect` uses `insert` as it allows greater flexibility. I guess the performance loss wouldn't be noticeable as `tail` just sets index. However, to get best performance, do not define `output` as `copy []`, but reserve some space with `output: make block expected-size` so there's no need to auto-expand `output` buffer.

Comment: I really need to transfer the documentation about the `/into` option to a more accessible location. There shouldn't be a reason why the behavior of `collect/into` would be unexpected, since the `/into` option should behave exactly the same for every Rebol function it's defined for. Its behavior is pretty thoroughly standardized.